# Pandas groupby summarize binary variable to indicate existence of an element?

Tags: pandas

I currently have the following dataframe

```
   A  B  C
0  x  1  1  
1  x  0  1
2  x  0  1
3  y  0  1
4  y  0  0
5  z  1  0
6  z  0  0
```

And i want

```
   A  B  C
0  x  1  1  
1  y  0  1
2  z  1  0
```

Basically summatize to show that in each grouped class if that variable exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about sorting the data as per order of higher to lower indicator value and then picking the first value for each group, In case any group lacks 1s on any row then we can use a filter condition by checking sum on each row should be greater than equal to 1.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z'], 'A': [1,0,0,0,0,1,0], 'B': [1,1,1,1,0,0,0]})
newdf = df.sort_values(['x', 'A', 'B'],ascending=[True, False, False]).groupby(['x']).first().reset_index()
newdf.loc[newdf.sum(axis=1) > 0,:]
```

**Output**:

```
 #      x   A   B
 #   0  x   1   1
 #   1  y   0   1
 #   2  z   1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of `existence` is any value more than 0, you can do this:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).any()
```

which gives you a boolean dataframe indicating the presence of variable `B` or `C`:

```
   A      B      C
0  x   True   True
1  y  False   True
2  z   True  False
```

Comment: Thanks, but not what i asked for. I need to be able to summarize down the first table to above, not just check for a value >0

Comment: `if that variable exists or not`. If it is not what you asked for then kindly edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

What about taking the max?

```
df.groupby('A').max()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern that can be adapted more generally to any value -- i.e. not just checking for 1s:

```py
df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x: any(x == 1))
```

(Replace 1 with a different value if needed.)

This will actually produce a result with True/False values. If you need the result to be 1s and 0s:

```py
df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x: 1 if any(x == 1) else 0)
```

Comment: This comes close. However, it keeps all rows as long as there is a 1. This still produces more rows than what i need. (as long as the group contains a single 1 for that column, then it should be aggregated to a single row with a 1 for that column, if not 0)